# Operator overloading example not clear

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading

I'm curently learning about operator overloading and I found this example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MinMax
{
private:
    int m_nMin; // The min value seen so far
    int m_nMax; // The max value seen so far

public:
    MinMax(int nMin, int nMax)
    {
        m_nMin = nMin;
        m_nMax = nMax;
    }

    int GetMin() { return m_nMin; }
    int GetMax() { return m_nMax; }

    friend MinMax operator+(const MinMax &cM1, const MinMax &cM2);
    friend MinMax operator+(const MinMax &cM, int nValue);
    friend MinMax operator+(int nValue, const MinMax &cM);
};

MinMax operator+(const MinMax &cM1, const MinMax &cM2)
{
    // Get the minimum value seen in cM1 and cM2
    int nMin = cM1.m_nMin < cM2.m_nMin ? cM1.m_nMin : cM2.m_nMin;

    // Get the maximum value seen in cM1 and cM2
    int nMax = cM1.m_nMax > cM2.m_nMax ? cM1.m_nMax : cM2.m_nMax;

    return MinMax(nMin, nMax);
}

MinMax operator+(const MinMax &cM, int nValue)
{
    // Get the minimum value seen in cM and nValue
    int nMin = cM.m_nMin < nValue ? cM.m_nMin : nValue;

    // Get the maximum value seen in cM and nValue
    int nMax = cM.m_nMax > nValue ? cM.m_nMax : nValue;

    return MinMax(nMin, nMax);
}

MinMax operator+(int nValue, const MinMax &cM)
{
    // call operator+(MinMax, nValue)
    return (cM + nValue);
}

int main()
{
    MinMax cM1(10, 15);
    MinMax cM2(8, 11);
    MinMax cM3(3, 12);

    MinMax cMFinal = cM1 + cM2 + 5 + 8 + cM3 + 16;

    cout << "Result: (" << cMFinal.GetMin() << ", " <<
        cMFinal.GetMax() << ")" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand how does the line `MinMax cMFinal = cM1 + cM2 + 5 + 8 + cM3 + 16;` work.

When this is calculated it becomes `MinMax cMFinal = MinMax(3, 16)`. What happenes next? How does the compiler assign one object to another when I didn't define overloading assigment operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say you have two `MinMax` objects, `a` and `b`. Then when you have a line like

```
MinMax c = a + b;
```

Then the compiler translates it to the following

```
MinMax c = operator+(a, b);
```

In other words, it's like a normal function call.

If you do multiple operations, like

```
MinMax d = a + b + c;
```

then the compiler will internally generate temporary variables and use, like

```
MinMax compilerGeneratedTemporary = operator+(a, b);

MinMax d = operator+(compilerGeneratedTemporary, c);
```

---

If it's the *initialization* you're wondering about, then it's calling the `MinMax` *copy-constructor*.  When you declare and initialize an object variable at the same time then it's not an assignment, it just reuses the assignment operator.

The `operator+` functions return a `MinMax` object, which is passed to the class copy-constructor.

If a class doesn't have a copy-constructor, the compiler will generate one for you automatically (with a few exceptions, see the reference linked below).

[Read more about the copy-constructor here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor).

Comment: Copy-elison would occur here, would it not? And if it didn't wouldn't the move-constructor be called rather than the copy-constructor?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Yes copy-elision would occur, but I'll save that for another question (when the OP wonders why his/her own copy-constructor isn't called). :)